# How can I override location of the swagger.yaml file?

Tags: node.js, swagger-2.0

As per the [swagger-node documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/blob/master/docs/swagger-file.md), the `swagger.yaml` file needs to be in `project/api/swagger/swagger.yaml`. How can I override this? I want my `swagger.yaml` to be at the root of the project directory, i.e. `project/swagger.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through the index.js file as

```
var spec = fs.readFileSync('./api/swagger.yaml', 'utf8');
var swaggerDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);
```

In the above , you can point to your swagger.yaml file from any location, even from a URL.

You can as well generate your sample node server side code using the http://editor.swagger.io/#/

1. load your yaml / javascript specification
2. use the menu option Generate Server -> node.js
3. in the generated package you can find the index.js, where you can modify the swagger.yaml file as explained above.